# Lost sound to monitor 20.04

Tags: sound

For some reason I no longer have any sound to my monitor plugged in by the 3.5mm Jack from the Speaker output. Plugging my monitor into phone sound comes through the monitors speakers so that rules out the monitor and the cable being the issue, the only noise I hear is a pop sound from the monitor.

The soundcard is... a 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller

The result of `$ sudo dmesg | grep -i audio`

```
    pacmd list cards |egrep -i "output|active" Defaultsink name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
Default source name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
        output:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Output (priority 39268, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analogue Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo/#1: Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
    sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
1 source output(s) available.
    source: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-id:org.gnome.VolumeControl"
```

If anything there helps. I can see looking at sound settings that the sound bar is moving up and down.
[sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBxcS.png)

What it looks like using Alsamixer

[Alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGnCQ.png)

Sound was previously working.

Answer (score 0):

I regularly lose sound to my 3.5mm (jack) speakers. When I open settings and test the output, I hear nothing. Changing output to headset and changing it back also doesn't help.

Strangely, changing audio output from a GNOME-extension solves my problem. Maybe you should give it a try.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/

You could also run `alsamixer` on terminal, press `F6` and check if your output is listed.

Comment: Hello buddy, thanks for your reply, in sound settings and the gnome extension you advised the only option I have is "speakers built in audio" nothing else is listed.

Please see attached image for the screenshot of alsamixer

Comment: You could also try `pulseaudio -k`, open a Youtube video (refresh the page) and see if it helps. 
[link](https://img.webme.com/pic/o/onsrcom/alsamixer-sample.png) This is what I see on alsamixer. I would try to connect a bluetooth speaker just to test if changing outputs solves the problem.

Comment: A unfortunately I don't have bluetooth on this desktop. However when I try Pulseaudio both "Line Out" and "headphones" says unlpugged, not sure if this has any relevance?